# How can I wait for ABPeoplePickerNavigationController be dismissed

Tags: iphone, addressbook

How can I wait for the contact to be chosen in my address book, before going on?

Hereunder the code I use

```
BPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

//following code
```

Right now it just proceeds with executing the code...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing the delegate methods?

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

If you are, move the "following code" into the delegate method, so after the user picks a person you can move on.